# how to generate a PrintWriter and write stuff to a JTextArea or equal

Tags: java, swing

I have a Problem, I dont know how to create a `PrintWriter` and then write the stuff to a `JTextArea`.

I have a library which want a PrintWriter in a method which I want to use to get some output. But I dont know how to generate a instance of the `PrintWriter` and then add the information to a JTextArea.

Anybody can help me?

I need s.th. like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(...);
foo.print(pw);
```

Comment: Have a good search of this site as this sort of question gets asked about once every 2 weeks or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter` can wrap another `Writer` and pass along everything written to it.  You can use a `StringWriter` to write to a string buffer, then get the contents of the buffer using `toString` when you're done.

```
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(buffer);
foo.print(writer);

String contents = buffer.toString();
myTextArea.setText(contents);
```

This only writes to the textarea once the library method finishes writing to the `PrintWriter` though.  Did you need it to update the textarea while the library method is executing?

Comment: I'm betting that the OP is looking to redirect output to a JTextArea, but we'll have to wait for his reply.